# Firefox MAC v30 with proxy needs authenticate"Cache Access Denied"

Tags: macos, firefox, authentication, proxy

Firefox was working perfectly before we've updated it to version 30.0. It seems that the new version does not like our Proxy setting which needs users to auth with their AD accounts.

In the past version, Firefox will pop-up a box that allow you to type in the username and password, which works perfect. However, it does not pop-up anymore and gives me this error message.

The following error was encountered:
   Cache Access Denied. 
Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:

http://www.google.com.au/url?
from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.

I try to manually set up the username in key chain and allow firefox to access it but Firefox seems do not access that key chain at all.

Is anyone have the issue with the proxy which needs authenticate in Firefox30.0? Does anyone know the possible solutions?

Many thanks!

Shuopan

trouble shoot update-----------------------------------------
Quite interestingly, Firefox will work for 1 minute after I am using Safari with that Auth proxy. However, if I am not touching Safari for 1 or 2 minutes, Firefox will stop working and pop up the similar error message.

tried network.http.use-cache = false but not work

Thanks

Comment: We find Philipp's solution is helpful.

"hello, this might be due to the disabling of certain insecure authentication protocols in firefox 30: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/30.0/releasenotes/#whatsnew

you can try to enter about:config into the firefox address bar (confirm the info message in case it shows up) & search for the preference named network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1. double-click it and change its value to true."

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/30.0/releasenotes/#whatsnew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find Philipp's solution is helpful.

This might be due to the disabling of certain insecure authentication protocols in firefox 30: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/30.0/releasenotes/#whatsnew

You can do the following:

1. Enter `about:config` into the Firefox address bar (confirm the info message in case it shows up)
2. Search for the preference named `network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1`. Double-click it and change its value to true.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/30.0/releasenotes/#whatsnew